Git over SSH fails to find repo on in-house server, even though SSH appears to connect
I want git to be able to push to a remote server that is in our company's local network.
Git is not able to access the remote repo over SSH, even though it appears to be able to access the server itself.
I've been able to establish an SSH connection to my in-house server (a windows machine).
I ultimately want to add the server as a git remote.
Git has a remote configured that I have tried several different urls for, usually looking like this:
 - ssh://admin@ipaddress/
 - ssh://admin@ipaddress/gitTest.git
 - ssh://admin@ipaddress/gitTest/.git
 - ssh://admin@ipaddress/c/gitTest/
 - etc.

I know that git is able to communicate with the server because the server requests the password for the admin user.  If I type the password wrong, it rejects it.  If I type it right, it instead always returns:
fatal: ''gitTest'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
I've also tried initing a bare repo in either C:/ or C:/Users/Admin/.
I have also confirmed that trying to clone from the remote repo has the same result.
I don't know where it's looking for the repo, or if it's failing for some other reason. I tried lots of different URL examples that I found online for windows. Windows defender firewall is totally turned OFF on both the client and server. Again, I can SSH into the server in the terminal, but git fails in this way every time.  It seems very weird.  What else could be going wrong?

How did you create the gitTest repository? Where did you create the gitTest repository? If you simply ssh admin@ipaddress, what is your current directory?

I created a gitTest repo under C:/ and under C:/Users/Admin/.  If I ssh in, it puts me in C:/Users/Admin/.  I have tried both doing git init and git init --bare

If you do git ls-remote admin@ipaddress:gitTest (in that specific format) with the correct username, IP, and path relative to C:\Users\Admin, does it return a list of refs? Also, which Git client are you using?

git ls-remote admin@ipaddress:gitTest throws the same error.  I am using the git bash terminal for windows.
